# how to join more than two mdx queries

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap-cube

i need two join 6 queries in mdx which are fetching result from olap cube .
problem is that all queries have different where condition and i want to join them on the basis of rows. the query is

```
WITH
MEMBER MEASURES.CONSTANTVALUE AS 0
SELECT 
Union(MEASURES.CONSTANTVALUE,[Measures].[Totalresult])  on 0,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize(Filter ({[keyword].[All keywords]},([Measures].[Totalresult]=0)))} ON 1
FROM [Advancedsearch]
WHERE {[Path].[/Search]}
```

In above the filter will be changed in different queries
how can we join this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that a cross product between the list of filters and your existing set on the rows should either already give you what you want, or be a starting point for further refinement of requirements not stated so far in your question:
This would mean something like

```
NON EMPTY 
{[Path].[/Search], [Path].[/Search2]}
*
{Hierarchize(Filter ({[keyword].[All keywords]}, ([Measures].[Totalresult]=0)))}
ON 1
```

(guessing your second filter would be `[Path].[/Search2]`) instead of your original

```
NON EMPTY 
{Hierarchize(Filter ({[keyword].[All keywords]}, ([Measures].[Totalresult]=0)))}
ON 1
```

and omitting the `WHERE`.